# how to start a file necesary glibc 2.17 without uid0?

Tags: root, vps, glibc

I need a solution or a improvization how to start a file with this error " : /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ........ ", i need a resolve how to start or how to resolve this error without uid0, a file, a launcher, anyway, i dont have uid0, and i have more servers, and at all servers i need to start this script, and i dont know how to start, because its this problem ... and i dont have uid0 at 90% from all servers

Comment: this problem its 90% from cases in centos sistem...

Comment: Probably something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, given that you have the necessary version of libraries with you.

Comment: and exista one method to start the file without have uid0 ? ... a portable file, or a portable installer or anyway, any ideea its okay